# How can i call hyperlink from my wordpress custom fields?

Tags: php, wordpress

I can not call custom field data into href.
Code:

```
enter code here

<?php foreach($books as $book) {?>
<li><a href="http://localhost/porospor-wp/<?php echo $book_page; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $book ?>" /></a></li><?php } ?>
```

Comment: ummm, what's `$book_page`? It's not defined anywhere. Did you mean `$book`?

Comment: <?php $book_page = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'book_page'); ?>

Comment: <?php $books = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'book_img', false); ?>

Comment: did you add `global $post;` before using `$post`?

Comment: Didn't before. Just now I have added global $post. But don't work.

Comment: When I hover my image it's shown : http://localhost/porospor-wp/Array

Comment: Hey, we cannot reach that URL, it's on your computer and not on the internet.

Comment: I just need custom value into my hyperlink:                                 Example: <a href="Custom field"><img src="image.png"></a> Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you have each book as an actual page in wordpress with a parent page of books you could loop through the pages like this:

```
<?php

$books = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );?>

<ul>

<?php foreach( $books as $book ) {?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $book->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $book->post_title; ?></a></li>
<?php } // End ForEach ?>

</ul>
```

In your question you have an image as the link so you could add a post thumbnail to the single book page and then display that as the image in the link by changing the standard code to this:

```
<?php

$books = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );?>

<ul>

<?php foreach( $books as $book ) {?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $book->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($book->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></a></li>
<?php } // End ForEach ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: ?php $book_page = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'book_page'); ?>        <?php $books = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'book_img', false); ?>         <?php foreach($books as $book) {?>
<li><a href="http://localhost/porospor-wp/<?php echo $book_page; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $book ?>" /></a></li><?php } ?>

Comment: Sorry could you please explain?

Comment: I just need custom value into my hyperlink: Example: <a href="Custom field"><img src="image.png"></a> Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible. There are also many ways, some better than others. Could you explain how you are setting up the custom fields. For example do you have a page with a load of custom fields or like my first example?